# PySpark regular expression pattern matching

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert below regular expression to pyspark.

Ex: +420602642919- these kind of phone number we need to filter using regular expressions

```
("/^((\+|00)(42)|0)?((060|660|664|676|68[0-1]|688)([0-9]){7}|(699)([0-9]){8})$/")
```

How to achieve this in Pyspark?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Normally you should be able to use the mentioned regex immediately with one of Spark regex functions

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your regex with the [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike) column function as shown below:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

#your initial dataframe
l = [('+420602642919',)
,('blabla',)]

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, ['someText'])

yourregex = '^((\+|00)(42)|0)?((060|660|664|676|68[0-1]|688)([0-9]){7}|(699)([0-9]){8})$'

#adding a column
df.withColumn('match', df.someText.rlike(yourregex)).show()

#or filtering
df.filter(df.someText.rlike(yourregex)).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-----+
|     someText|match|
+-------------+-----+
|+420602642919| true|
|       blabla|false|
+-------------+-----+

+-------------+
|     someText|
+-------------+
|+420602642919|
+-------------+
```